# Unicode Rs. symbol ₹ not visible in application

Tags: c#, wpf, unicode

I have just completed working on a project in WPF and C#. I have also used Crystal Reports. I have used the symbol ₹ as the currency symbol in my application which works fine in the windows as well as in the reports on my system. The problem appeared when I executed the application on another machine. What might be the possible cause of this issue? It shows a square in all the places where I used ₹. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do I need to install some kind of updates on the target machines?

Comment: A square means that the machine doesn't have a font that can display that character.  Common on XP for example.  You didn't document the characteristics of that machine well enough to propose a solution.  Post to a computer interest site like superuser.com to find help with that.

Comment: Its happening on Windows 7 though I developed on 8

Comment: Will installing the Segoi UI font help? That is the font I have used.

Comment: Segoi UI will work with Indian rupees text. '₹'

Answer (score 2):

The character “₹” U+20B9 INDIAN RUPEE SIGN was added to Unicode in version 6.0, released in 2010. It generally takes over ten years before new characters become widely available. One reason to this is that there is no automatic update system for fonts.

Some characters get implemented faster than others, for commercial and political reasons, and INDIAN RUPEE SIGN is really on a fast track. [Font support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/fontsupport.htm) is fairly good – but does not apply to any versions of fonts released before October 2010.

Thus, you may wish to embed a font into your application. This requires permission from copyright holder. For example, Segoe UI is not a free font (though you might ask its vendor about the rights). However, you could use e.g. [DejaVu fonts](http://dejavu-fonts.org).

Comment: I installed the font explicitly on the Target Machine and it is showing the symbol on the screen. But still it is not printing it in the printouts and the reports.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory named “Fonts” in your Silverlight project and copy the font file inside that.[image]

Now go to the properties pane of the font file from your Visual Studio IDE itself. Select “BlendEmbeddedFont” from the “Build Action” dropdown and set “Copy to Output Directory” as “Do not copy”

[image]

Go to your XAML and add the following code and be sure that you inserted the proper path and filename to the embedded FontFamily.

```
<TextBlock Text="Product Rate: ` 103.50" 
            FontFamily="/IndianRupeeDemo;component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#Rupee Foradian" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="32"/>
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: A little confusion. One, I am not working on a Silverlight project, its on WPF using C#. Two, I also need the same font in the crystal reports. I don't have any specific font as well. Please suggest.

Comment: Done, I just needed to restart my the computer after installing fonts.